# How to fix warning message related to Pantheon module?

Tags: updating

When I am running update.php, I am getting warning message. I am sure this is showing because the module was deleted without uninstalling. I am unable to find the Pantheon module or the module for which this warning is related.

> User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: pantheon.   For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in `_drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging()` (line 1143 of /homepages/46/d644118784/htdocs/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [module_missing_message_fixer](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer)

### with drush

you just need to run the following 2 commands

```
drush en module_missing_message_fixer
drush mmmff pantheon
```

### without drush using the user interface

1. Enable the module
2. make sure you have the permission Administer Module Missing Message Fixer
3. Go to: admin/config/system/module-missing-message-fixer

Comment: I enabled the module [module_missing_message_fixer](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer) but it not works.

Comment: just enabling the module will not do it ... did you follow the UI steps ? I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, there showed the module name and along with checkbox to remove the error. I did the same but the warning is still showing on update.php page

Comment: maybe try a cache rebuild `drush cr`

Comment: This was showing because of the pantheon module which was deleted after disable. I get the pantheon profile module and updated inside "profiles" and then on uninstall page (admin/modules/uninstall), the pantheon get listed to uninstall. After uninstalling from there the warning also get remove.